# How to convert integer to unsigned 32 bit in python?

Tags: python, int, bit, unsigned

For example, if we take `1` and transform it to unsigned 32-bits, it will be `00000000000000000000000000000001`

How could you achieve this in python?

Comment: `"{:032b}".format(1)`?

Comment: Do you mean for display purposes, or do you need to convert a number into a type that is exactly 32 bits (for example., to pack it into a structure)?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Please read about [the X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I need to convert it to exactly 32 bits.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/flipping-bits

Comment: The *solution* you want is the conversion, but it's not the actual problem you're trying to solve. The problem you're trying to solve may have *other* solutions. And by not telling us *why* you want this conversion it will make it harder to give you a solution that works in a satisfactory (for you) way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bin(1)[2:].zfill(32)
```

'00000000000000000000000000000001'

Comment: This code creates a *string* representing 32 bits as "0" or "1"; it doesn't actually create a 32-bit integer *value*.

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert(i):
    return int(bin(i+2**32)[-32:])

print convert(1)
print convert(32)
print convert(100)
print convert(-1)
print type(convert(1))
```

outputs

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000100000
00000000000000000000000001100100
11111111111111111111111111111111
<type 'long'>
```